# Add Company logo in top of the excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Need to add logo in the top of the excel file while downloading.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
string FileName = "MachinePlanning" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
GridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
GridView1.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Need to ask a question to get an answer.

Comment: Question asked..Need to add logo in top of excel

Comment: `Requirements instanceof Question == false`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it by Open XML or NPOI.Dll.

Below code will export excel with the company logo. but you need to add NPOI.DLL.

```
  public static MemoryStream ExportToExcelWithCompanyLogo(DataTable dt, string sheetName, string CompanyLogo,Dictionary<string, string> filters)
  {

  //Create new Excel Workbook
  var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  //Create new Excel Sheet
  var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(sheetName);

  // Add Image Section 
  var patriarch = sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
  HSSFClientAnchor anchor;
  anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, (short)1, 1, (short)5, 6);
  anchor.AnchorType = 2;

  string imagesPath = CompanyLogo;
  //grab the image file
  //imagesPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(imageLocation, "image.jpg");
  //create an image from the path
  System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagesPath);

  MemoryStream ims = new MemoryStream();
  //pull the memory stream from the image (I need this for the byte array later)
  image.Save(ims, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


  int index = workbook.AddPicture(ims.ToArray(), PictureType.JPEG);

  var picture = patriarch.CreatePicture(anchor, index);
  picture.Resize(0.8);
  //picture.LineStyle = HSSFPicture.LINESTYLE_DASHDOTGEL;
  sheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation = true;

  // End of Add image

  // font Style for Excel title
  HSSFFont hFont = (HSSFFont)workbook.CreateFont();
  hFont.FontHeightInPoints = 16;
  hFont.FontName = "Calibri";
  hFont.Boldweight = (short)NPOI.SS.UserModel.FontBoldWeight.Bold;

  HSSFCellStyle hStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
  hStyle.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
  hStyle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
  hStyle.SetFont(hFont);
  // end of excel title style

  // font for Table header Stylr
  HSSFFont thhFont = (HSSFFont)workbook.CreateFont();
  thhFont.FontHeightInPoints = 12;
  thhFont.FontName = "Calibri";
  thhFont.Boldweight = (short)NPOI.SS.UserModel.FontBoldWeight.Bold;

  HSSFCellStyle thhStyle = (HSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
  thhStyle.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
  thhStyle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
  thhStyle.SetFont(thhFont);
  // end of table header font



  var cra = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(6, 7, 4, 9);
  sheet.AddMergedRegion(cra);

  // Add filters to sheet
  int filterRows = 9;
  foreach (var key in filters)
  {
  var FilterRow = sheet.CreateRow(filterRows);
  FilterRow.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(key.Key + " : ");
  FilterRow.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(key.Value);
  filterRows++;
  }


  var HeaderRowNumber = 9 + filters.Keys.Count + 1;
  //Add rows
  var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(HeaderRowNumber);
  //int totalcolumns = dt.Columns.Count;
  int columncounter = 0;

  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
  foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
  {
  var cell = headerRow.CreateCell(columncounter + 1);
  cell.SetCellValue(c.ColumnName);
  cell.CellStyle = thhStyle;
  columncounter++;
  }
  //(Optional) freeze the header row so it is not scrolled
  //sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);
  int rowNumber = HeaderRowNumber + 1;
  int dtrowNumber = 1;
  //Populate the sheet with values from the grid data
  foreach (var rows in dt.Rows)
  {
  //Create a new Row
  var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);
  //Set cell Value
  for (int cellnumber = 0; cellnumber < columncounter; cellnumber++)
  row.CreateCell(cellnumber + 1).SetCellValue(dt.Rows[dtrowNumber - 1][cellnumber].ToString());
  rowNumber++;
  dtrowNumber++;
  }
  // create 2 blank rows
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
  //Create a new Row
  var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);
  //Set cell Value
  for (int cellnumber = 0; cellnumber < columncounter; cellnumber++)
  row.CreateCell(cellnumber + 1).SetCellValue("");
  rowNumber++;
  }

  // Add Date of extraction and source
  var extractedDate = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);
  var ecel = extractedDate.CreateCell(4);
  ecel.SetCellValue("Extracted Date : ");
  // ecel.CellStyle = hStyle;
  extractedDate.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd - MMM - yyyy"));
  rowNumber++;



  var Disclaimer = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);
  var dcel = Disclaimer.CreateCell(4);
  dcel.SetCellValue("Disclaimer : ");
  // dcel.CellStyle = hStyle;
  Disclaimer.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("All Rights Reserved.");
  rowNumber++;

  var Disclaimer1 = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);
  Disclaimer1.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Give some information at footer");
  rowNumber++;

  }
  else
  {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
  headerRow.CreateCell(i).SetCellValue("");
  }
  // End of add rows
  //Write the Workbook to a memory stream
  MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
  workbook.Write(output);
  return output;

  }
```

you can download NPOI.Dll from this link
[Download NPOI.dll](https://npoi.codeplex.com/releases)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hari, in your code you are converting HTTP content to Excel simply by changing its mine type. you need to create an excel at the server end. The above code can help you in this.

Comment: ok mohit ,so by my code i cant able to add excel logo right??.

Comment: Hari, if you want to do it from your code there is one tweak for it. add your logo along with your grid HTML  in hidden state and then try your code it can solve your problem.